# $T^2 (v)=-v \, \, \, \forall v \in\mathbb R ^n $ a linear transformation , find $n$ is even.

Tags: linear-transformations

> Let  $T:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n $ be a linear transformation satisfying  $ T ^2 (v)=-v $ for all   $v\in\mathbb R ^n $.
>
> Then show that:
>
> (A) $n$ is always even.
>
> (B) $T$ is an isomorphism
>
> (C) $T$ becomes a $\mathbb C$-linear isomorphism.

I proceed as

If we define  $T $ by $T:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2$ by $T(x_1, x_2)=(-x_2,x_1)$
Then $T^2=-Id $.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by point (C) ?

Comment: The question given as it is.  I  think field should be  $\mathbb C  $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the $\det$:
$$\det(T^2)=\det(T)^2=\det(-I_n)=(-1)^n$$
so $(-1)^n \geq 0$ i.e $n$ is even and  $\det(T) \neq 0$ as $\det(T)^2 \neq 0$.